# Check if values exist before INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

#### Background

I have an an application where users can submit reviews for a product. Users can also edit previously submitted reviews or submit another one for the same product.

I am implementing an "auto-save" feature that saves the form data once every X seconds. If the page is accidentally closed, the user can restore this "draft".

This is a simplified version of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `review_autosave_data` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `review_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `review` blob,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`product_id`, `user_id`),
  KEY `fk_review_autosave_data_review_id (`review_id`),
  KEY `fk_review_autosave_data_product_id (`product_id`),
  KEY `fk_review_autosave_data_user_id (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

**Bear in mind that this table only stores the drafts - not the actual reviews**. If we're editing a review `review_id` will point to that review. If we're in the process of creating a new review, this field will be `NULL`.

---

#### What's working

This is my query for inserting a new draft:

```
INSERT INTO review_autosave_data (review_id, product_id, user_id, review)
VALUES (25, 50, 1, "lorem ipsum")
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE review = "lorem ipsum";
```

This works fine for inserting **new** review-drafts. The indexes prevent inserting a new row where the combination of `product_id` and `user_id` already exist.

---

#### What's not working

My problem is for inserting drafts for **existing** reviews, where `review_id` needs to point to an existing review because, ideally, the index here needs to be the combination of `product_id`, `user_id` **and** `review_id`. Unfortunately in my case, the following applies:

> a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL

While there are questions and answers about the above quote, I'm not necessarily interested in achieving getting a null value be part of a unique index - but rather to find a workaround.

I guess I could first make a select query to check if the above combination exists, and if not proceed with the main query. But I'd like to get all that into one query if possible. Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is already quite long, so I tried trimming it as much as possible. If there's anything I've left out or needs clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `review_autosave_data` you can create two tabels like `review_insert_drafts` and `review_update_drafts` (one for new reviews and one for review updates).

```
CREATE TABLE `review_insert_drafts` (
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `review` blob,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `review_update_drafts` (
  `review_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `review` blob,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`review_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`review_id`) REFERENCES `reviews` (`id`)
);
```

(Not sure what the `name` column is good for.)

In your application you have to check if the user is writing a new review or is updating an existing one.

For new reviews you run:

```
INSERT INTO review_insert_drafts (product_id, user_id, review)
VALUES (50, 1, "lorem ipsum")
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE review = "lorem ipsum";
```

or

```
REPLACE INTO review_insert_drafts (product_id, user_id, review)
VALUES (50, 1, "lorem ipsum");
```

For review updates you run:

```
INSERT INTO review_update_drafts (review_id, review)
VALUES (25, "lorem ipsum")
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE review = "lorem ipsum";
```

or

```
REPLACE INTO review_update_drafts (review_id, review)
VALUES (25, "lorem ipsum");
```

Advantages: You have a clear design with clear unique keys and foreign keys.

Disadvantages: You have two tables containing similar data. So you have two different insert statements. And you will need a UNION statement if you want to combine the two tables (e.g. show all drafts for a user).

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this and it's probably the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I decided to go with this approach as it seems way more reasonable to just do it the easy way. As such, I have marked this answer as the "accepted" one. However, since it doesn't exactly address the question based on the database structure provided, I have awarded the bounty to the other answer which does that better.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `NULL`, use 0 to mean no review yet.

Then change `DEFAULT NULL` to `NOT NULL`.

Meanwhile, you may as well get rid of `id` and simply have `PRIMARY KEY(product_id, user_id, review_id)`

Also get rid of any index that is a prefix of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Why do you have the "review" as `BLOB`, when it is presumably "TEXT"?

Comment: Yeah thats a solution. I'd have to drop the foreign key though.

Comment: Is it possible to instead have one query that looks up the unique index (the combination of the product_id, user_id, and review_id) and if such row doesn't exist, proceed with the insertion? I can do this in separate queries, but both in one was tricky for me.

Comment: `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` does _not_ need a check before running it.  It _either_ updates or inserts.

Comment: Right, but I'd rather keep `null` if possible. So in that case the key will never exist because a column that has `null` basically cannot be part of such unique key. So rather than using 0 like you suggested (which is still a decent solution) I'd rather manually make this check. Does that make sense?

Comment: Since IODKU must have a UNIQUE index to check against, and NULL does not work 'right' for you, you are stuck with a check.

Comment: Okay. Is it possible to run that check in one (non-transactional) query?

Comment: You probably need to put the `SELECT` and IODKU in the _same_ transaction.  Else, another thread could sneak in.  (This provides another argument for using 0 instead of NULL.)

Comment: Right. So perhaps I could do `IF EXISTS SELECT ... THEN..` followed by the query above.

Comment: Interesting question -- I don't know if that is effectively 2 queries, hence needing BEGIN...COMMIT.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Though I did not proceed with this solution, it does answer my initial question better and accounts for the existing db structure. As such, I have awarded the bounty to this answer, but accepted another which is the one that worked for me better.

Answer (score 1):

Just make 2nd table that will hold posted reviews. And once users posts review move the data there.

That will eliminate your problem and make things clearer. 
You will have one place for drafts that should not be posted anywhere and one table that will have posted review that you want to display in various places. Your current table name as well suggests that it hold only autosave data and no posted data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have such table. I haven't added it here because it's largely irrelevant to the problem. The dilemma here is how to store drafts for new reviews, that yet do not exist in the "reviews table", and how to store drafts for existing reviews.

Comment: You can see this as well from my table description. `review_id` is a foreign key to the reviews table. The one I provide stores drafts only.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Thinking about it, I don't understand why you want to keep relationship between draft and existing review. UserId and ProductId should be enough to join them if needed.

Comment: Well that's the thing. A user can post multiple reviews per product. In any event, I need to account for the fact that a draft may, or may not, be linked to an existing review before inserting. The unique index works, but not when a new draft is created for new reviews - because instead of replacing the last autosave with the new one, it creates a new row.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO review_autosave_data (review_id, product_id, user_id, review)
SELECT 25, 50, 1, "lorem ipsum"
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT review_id FROM review_autosave_data 
        WHERE product_id=50 AND user_id = 1 AND review_id IS NULL)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE review = "lorem ipsum";
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try it on monday and let you know.

Comment: This works for the `INSERT` part, but it doesn't do anything `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try inserting a new row without review_id?

```
INSERT INTO review_autosave_data (product_id, user_id, review)
VALUES (50, 1, "lorem ipsum")
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE review = "lorem ipsum";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try make `product_id` and `user_id` your primary key:

```
PRIMARY KEY(`product_id`, `user_id`)
```

and add review_id as your `UNIQUE KEY`

Answer (score 1):

Why not completely move the problem from DB?

Presumably when your application submits the autosave 'request' it will get some kind of confirmation that it happened right? You could send back 'ID' of the insert so application can then save into that record explicitly - aka, first autosave will be different then the rest and subsequent autosaves will just update specific autosave record.

This completely avoids problems in your DB layer I think... you will have two queries though, one for insert for new draft, and then another to update specific draft, no fancy keys required.