# Make Unique key work with NULL values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, chat

I have created chat application and its chat seen sql look like below

```
chat_seen --table name
--Columns---
from_user  | to_id  | group_id | unseen_count
```

It works like this:When group_id is NULL it means that this is one to one chat,if group_id is not null from_user is final user which wrote message and to_id is user who is group member.I have Foreign key on group_id and it reference to group table,and I have Unique key for 3 column(from_user,to_id,group_id),When group_id is null it should work because from_user and to_id should be unique in one to one chat ,but in the group chat it should be unique per group_id,this will work if Unique key works with NULL VALUES because if it works it will count group_id NULL values as group_id and per NULL group from_user and to_id will be unique.I cant change group_id to anything because it has foreign key.

I also want to achieve that if group_id is not null to_id should has Foreign key and it should reference to group member,group_id is not NULL it should reference to user_id in user table.

**Updated version with examples**

When someone in the group write message per message I insert or update(if exists) to chat_seen table for each user,it means that if Group contain 20 people per each message I will update or insert 20 column to notify them later if they dont see chat.And I update unseen_count per each user.

What should I do?any suggestion?

Comment: That doesn't work (for good reasons). Technically, you could just add add a new column with `group_memberid`, and leave `to_id``null` for group chats, then create a unique key for both combinations (groupchat and 1-1-chat). On the other hand, you might have some problems in your design (although I don't know your db, so it's just a guess): a) group-memberships can change, so a foreign key to the group table might not work (e.g. if you leave and rejoin, you missed some messages) and b) in a group chat, `from` usually is not relevant for `seen`, so maybe `group_id` take the place of `from`.

Comment: And a general comment: it's a little bit hard to follow your design and your requirements from just your text description. It would be a lot easier to follow if you add some sample data (and your other tables, especially the group-member-table would be nice). And because I didn't mention it: the sql standard defines the behaviour of unique keys the way they work in mysql: if you have a `null` in a key column, they are not not-unique.

Comment: Assigning some significance to NULL, beyond missing value, therefore unknown value, is generally full of pitfalls.  This is one of them.  You are trying to make NULL mean something different than SQL wants it to mean.

Comment: @Solarflare to_id will not be null it will be user_id which should recieve notification.I use this system to notify user when new messages come because if new message come user unseen_count should increase (see update I suddenly put there message before but I have fixed it is unseen_count)and user should get notification count.

Comment: @Bucky I meant something like this: `to, from, group, from_grp`, and the 2 unique keys `(to, from)` and `(to, group, from_grp)` (or  `(from, to)` and `(from, group, to_grp)`). Depending on the message type, leave either `from` or `group, from_grp` `null`, then only one of the unique keys will be relevant (because the other will contain a key column with `null`, which doesn't fail the unique constraint). At least technically. As I said, I don't think your database design really fits here.

Comment: @Solarflare you example is great but I want to sql use `(from, to)` unique  key when group_id is null,but when group_id is not null I want to use `(from, group, to_grp)` Unique key,How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Solarflare I solved problem with a little bit hack,I will post new answer now if you are interested you can check it

Comment: This question looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872068/check-if-values-exist-before-insert-into-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem with a little bit hack.When one to one chat insert to chat_seen table first I check from_user is null or not because I allowed from_user can be null(I will explain it later).Then I have created from_user and to_id Unique key.Now I have 2 Unique key 1)from_user and to_id and another is 2)to_id and group_id(I have delete from_user from this unique key).When user insert to chat_seen table with group_chat mod,I insert null to from_user because I want to ignore 1) Uniuqe key for groups,if group is null it means one to one chat 2) unique key will be ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the Id field for groups and the Id field for users from the same autosequence generator.  This guarantees that a given Id can be either a user or a group, but not both.

Now eliminate to Group_Id in your table.  Instead, just store the groupId in the To_Id field for group messages, and make the From_Id and To_Id unique.

If you want to look at only the messages sent to groups, just join with the groups table.  The messages for individuals will drop out of the join.

Likewise, if you want to look at only the messages to individuals, just join with the users table.  The messages for groups will drop out of the join.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I think this sentence can solve my problem "Assign the Id field for groups and the Id field for users from the same autosequence generator.",but it is a little bit unclear ,can you please provide me details about it? What does it mean "same autosequence generator".Should I give foreing key ,but I cant give 2 foreign key to one column

Comment: I know how to do that in some database systems, but not mysql.  I'll leave it to mysql users to help you with that part.

Comment: The real deal is that users and groups are both recipients, but they go in different tables.  By using the same autosequence, I'm really sidestepping the full blown modelling answer.  It's to define a recipients table, and then used shared primary key to replicate recipientId as the userid or the groupid.  That's overkill in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,If I replicate them how will I able to detect that it is user_id or group_id?
I have solved my question at stackoverflow.com/questions/40447156/make-unique-key-work-with-null-values/40449056?noredirect=1#40451013

Answer (score 0):

[unique index allows duplicates with null values](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8173) - discussed and rejected